# How does performing processing server-side affect the overall performance of a site?

Tags: sql, node.js, asynchronous, server-side

I'm working on an application that will process data submitted by the user, and compare with past logged data. I don't need to return or respond to the post straight away, just need to process it. This "processing" involves logging the response (in this case a score from 1 to 10) that's submitted by the user every day, then comparing it against the previous scores they submitted. Then if something found, do something (not sure yet, maybe email).

Though I'm worried about the effectiveness of doing this and how it could affect the site's performance. I'd like to keep it server side so the script for calculating isn't exposed. The site is only dealing with 500-1500 responses (users) per day, so it isn't a massive amount, but just interested to know if this route of processing will work. The server the site will be hosted on won't be anything special, probably a small(/est) AWS instance.

Also, will be using Node.js and SQL/PSQL database.

Comment: Why don't you put together a small example and do some profiling? That's really the only way to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how do you implement this processing algorithm and how heavy on resources this algorithm is.
If your task is completely syncronous its obviously going to block any incoming requests for your application until its finished.

You can make this "processing-application" as a seperate node process and communicate with it only what you need.

If this is a heavy task and you worry about performance its a good idea to make it a seperate node process so it does not impact the serving of the users.

I recoment to google for "node js asynchronous" to better understand the subject.

Comment: Right, I can see how async would fit this perfectly since it can "wait til resources are free". But, the "processing" will consist of a database query of a user to get their logs, and a simple check for repeat values (e.g. if repeat low value over a period). So I'd assume this would be considered a light task, and the database shouldn't get too big, having ~800 logs per day would still take 3.5 years to hit a million, so the (again) shouldn't take too long. `SELECT uid, score, date FROM logs WHERE uid == {usersId}`, or something along those lines.

Comment: I believe you can measure this by checking the response time. If it takes too long to respond to your request it maybe a good idea to have a multiple webservers. If your tasks is heavier than a simple query in my scenario i was think about a service that is doing analysis and i never know when it finishes and it may take minutes i would go for a seperate process and send email about its results.

Comment: And under multiple webserbers i mean multiple nodes so that the request may be handled by a second node process.

Comment: Alright, sounds like a good idea. Do you think it would be be better (or possible ) to hand off the submission to the second node or to accept that route with the second node?

Comment: You can set up the loadbalancer to manage the requests to a specific node based on url i think.